# rotateY image horizontally for IOS

Tags: react-native, animation, rotation

im trying to spin an image using react native Animation on rotateY

the problem is that in iOS its only spinning half of the image compare to android that doing that perfectly

I'm attaching link for android and iOS performs:

ios https://streamable.com/nmqin

android https://streamable.com/64p25

```
animateLogo () {
   this.animatedLogo.setValue(0)
   Animated.timing(
   this.animatedLogo, {
     toValue: 1,
     duration: 1500,
     easing: Easing.linear,

   }
 ).start();
 }

render() {
   const spin = this.animatedLogo.interpolate({
     inputRange: [0,1],
     outputRange: ['0deg', '1440deg']
   });

    return (
     <View style={styles.container}>

  <Animated.Image
       style={[styles.logo,{
         width:110,
         height:150,
         transform: [{ rotateY: spin }]
       }]}
         source={require('./assets/logo_white1.png')}
     />
</View>)}
```

I had been trying adding inside the transform the respective but didn't work

Comment: anyone has an answer?